# How to iterate and update records?

Tags: node.js, vba, typescript, sqlite

I describe what I'm trying to do in VBA because it's the language I know best :

```
'Declare a recordset which will iterate through our records 
Dim rs as DAO.recordset

'Setup a connection to our data store with the table/query we want to process records in
Set rs = dbengine.workspaces.opendatabase('path/to/database').openrecordset('select * from sometable')

rs.movefirst
Do Until rs.eof
  'put record in edit mode 
  rs.Edit
  rs!field = 'some value I want' 
  'put record in update mode 
  rs.update 
  rs.movenext
loop
```

It's looping and setting values. What I need is more complex (updating based on what is in the next row after and all of that), but I can figure that out myself once I understand how to iterate through records and perform updates at record level.

What I have now:

```
//this function is just is called by another function. processRecord is what does the individual record processing 
async function processRecords(db: Database, SQL: string, processRecord: any) {
  db.each(SQL, async(e,r) => {
    if(e) {
      reject(e);
    } else {
      try {
        await processRecord(db,r);
        resolve(true);
      }
      catch(e) {
        reject(e); 
      }
    }
  });
}
async function processRecord(db: Database, r: Row) {
   try {
     //execute a query against the current row we are processing
     //SQL for updates uses a select in SET clause to pull data from the record with the next rowid
     //executeQuery is a "promisified" db.run
     executeQuery(db,updateSQL,r.rowID);
 
   } catch(e : any) {
     throw e;
   }
} 

//I borrowed this from somewhere else and modified it a bit. 
function executeQuery(db: Database, SQL: string, params: any = []) : Promise<number> {
  return new Promise(resolve,reject) => {
    db.Run(SQL,params,function(e) {
      if(e) {
        reject(e);
      } else {
        resolve(this.changes); 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

How to iterate through records and perform updates at record level?

Comment: Thanks for the edits, a bit less meandering now :)

Comment: I ended up doing a couple things to work around limitations on this

1) I switched to better-sqlite3 
2) I enabled WAL mode
3) I was able to iterate through records, but because the update queries weren't affecting the pulled records in the same way recordset object does in VBA, I just switched to pulling all rows, looping through the array of javascript objects and then pushing back the updates into a separate table.